# How to store and update the size, height, and imbalance in a binary search tree?

Tags: binary-search-tree

The goal is to have a binary search tree where each subtree/node always knows its size, height, and imbalance (along with it's value and left + right subtrees).

The variables for each BST are:
'left', 'right', 'parent', 'value', 'height', 'size', 'imbalance'

During insert I recursively increment the size variable of all parents of the new node. I'm having trouble figuring out what to do for height/imbalance.

This is so the program can quickly get the height, size and imbalance of any part of the tree.

Comment: How do you define balance ? If it's just number of children on left/right then you can add when inserting on the left, subtract when inserting on the right ... for height, you need to have your insertion return 1 if it added to the height or not, and change depending on that ... you may need to keep height on left and right and combine this notions ...

Comment: The balance/imbalance is the absolute value of the difference in height of the two subtrees. The height is defined as the longest downward path to a leaf node. And the size is simply the size of the left node + the size of the right node + 1 (all nodes in that subtree).

Comment: then you can keep two heights, height of the left and height of the right subtrees; imbalance is their difference, and height is the max of those; you just need to update when inserting (but be careful, as an insertions doesn't increase the height of all the subtrees)